# After conda update --all, Qt breaks in iPython

Tags: linux, pyqt, pip, ipython, conda

I ran "conda update --all" and it updated a lot of things, including Python itself (from 3.5.2-0 to 3.5.3-1, I think) and PyQt. I have used Pip in the past; I imagine they might conflict. Now when I try to run an iPython session, as soon as I evaluate a plot, the kernel dies, and I get a lot of "ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtGui'" errors.

I opened a Python shell and found that QtGui exists in PyQt5 but not PyQt4:

```
>>> import PyQt4
>>> import PyQt4.QtGui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtGui'
>>> import PyQt5
>>> import PyQt5.QtGui
```

I run Linux, specifically Ubuntu 16.04.

What should I do?

Here's the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 116, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 46, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/pdb.py", line 75, in <module>
    import code
  File "/home/jeff/stats_with_luis/code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/api.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pandas.io.clipboard.clipboard import read_clipboard
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboard/__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
    copy, paste = determine_clipboard()
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboard/__init__.py", line 76, in determine_clipboard
    return init_qt_clipboard()
  File "/home/jeff/apps/pythoon-libs/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboard/clipboards.py", line 49, in init_qt_clipboard
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtGui'
```

Comment: I don't have a simple solution but some tips. First check if you have a `QT_API` environment variable defined. See [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html?highlight=qt_api#pyqt-and-pyside) for more info. Second, how did you install `IPython` and `pandas`? With pip or with conda? You can check this with the `conda list` command. I recommend to use conda where possible and only use pip if no conda package is available. Installing PyQt with pip into a conda environment will break your installation!

Comment: Thanks! I ended up reinstalling the OS (ubuntu 16.04). Then I made a conda environment for iPython, which is working great.